# Há relação entre as interjeições caraca e caraças?

Tags: diferenças-transatlânticas, origem-histórica

Em Portugal, é muito comum o uso da interjeição **caraças** (1), e, pelo menos no Rio de Janeiro (não sei se noutros sítios do Brasil), a interjeição **caraca** (2) tem exactamente o mesmo significado. São sempre empregues de maneira informal.

Exemplos:

1. Caraças, assustei-me!
2. Caraca! Essa comida é muito boa!

Existe, dada tal parecença, alguma relação?

O Dicionário Priberam [indica](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/caraca) uma suposta origem, [caraco](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/caraco), que não é muito verossímil.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O [Aulete também diz que a interjeição ***caraca***](http://www.aulete.com.br/caraca) tem origem em [***caraco***](http://www.aulete.com.br/caraco), que é um termo mineiro pejorativo para pessoas de língua espanhola, e que, por sua vez, ainda segundo o Aulete, vem do próprio espanhol *carago*, ou seja, *caralho*. Isto é que me surpreendeu. [***Carago***](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/carago) é um termo do norte de Portugal; no dicionário da [Real Academia Española](http://dle.rae.es/?w=carago&m=form&o=h) aparece, mas com um significado que não tem nada a ver. Terá sido um engano, o termo espanhol é [***carajo***](http://dle.rae.es/?w=carajo&m=form&o=h), que é, segundo o dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa, a origem de *carago*. [***Caralho***](http://www.aulete.com.br/caralho) e *carajo* têm ambas possivelmente origem no latim *caraculu*, ou pequeno pau.

Seja esta ou não a origem de *caraca*, eu creio que existe de facto uma relação entre as interjeições *caraca, [**caraças**](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/cara%C3%A7as)*, e *carago*. Parecem ser todas variantes relativamente aceitáveis de [***caralho***](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/caralho). Como interjeições, são todas, em grande medida, usadas para exprimir a mesma ideia ou sentimento. Uma diferença é que *caralho* é muito mais grosseiro, e é também a única destas palavras que significa pénis. Também [***caramba***](http://www.aulete.com.br/caramba) é originalmente uma [variação eufemística espanhola](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=caramba) de *carajo*.

A grosseria extrema é provavelmente uma das razões para o aparecimento de alternativas foneticamente parecidas. A pessoa pode dar a entender *caralho* sem o dizer. Com o tempo, a associação pode até perder-se. Outro exemplo provável disto é *fosca-se, fosga-se* e *fónix* em Portugal. Este [artigo na Veja](http://veja.abril.com.br/blog/sobre-palavras/consultorio/caramba-puxa-e-outros-eufemismos/) também atribui a este fenómeno a origem de *caraca, caramba* e *puxa*.

Comment: É curiosa e até engraçada essa origem comum, partilhada pelos diferentes termos. _Cacete_ também pode ser usado assim, mas é um pouco mais grosseiro que os outros.

Comment: É, estas coisas são fascinantes. *Cacete*, imagino que seja por associação direta ao pénis, pela forma da coisa. Nas outras é pelo som da palavra. O substantivo *caraça* vem de *cara*, mas não vejo outra razão para a interjeição *caraças* que não a semelhança sonora com *caralho*.

Comment: @Jacinto já pensaste como os Espanhóis dizem *carajo*? Fica com um sonoridade muito parecida com *carago*. Sabes que o norte tem muitas influências espanholas.

Comment: É possível, mas isso não justificaria o Aulete escrever *carago* em vez de *carajo*. Agora, *carago* pode ter entrado em Portugal pela Galiza já como *carago*.

Comment: (Salvo seja... :)

Comment: Pois, a língua portuguesa é muito traicoeira.

Answer (score 5):

**"caraca"** é gíria relativamente recente (ouvi pela primeira vez no Rio de Janeiro em alguma época da década de 90 do século passado). Foi muito usada por adolescentes mas hoje em dia não tanto.  É uma interjeição e tem o mesmo significado que **"caramba!"** (pouco vulgar) ou **"caralho!"** (muito vulgar) e pode ter tido a sua origem em uma dessas duas palavras. Nunca ouvi a palavra "caraças", interjeição usada em Portugal, e não tenho vivência para afirmar que signifique a mesma coisa que "caraca". Pelos exemplos postados na pergunta, parece que sim.

> - [**Expressão de espanto, surpresa. - "Caraca, não sabia que você tinha sofrido um acidente!"**](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/caraca/)